# How to add Xamarin Community Toolkit Popup inside a ContentPage in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-community-toolkit

I want to add **Xamarin.CommunityToolkit - Popup** inside a `ContentPage`. I don't want to make seperate files for each Popup. Hence I want them to be inside `ContentPage` on which the popup will be shown. Is there anyway I can achieve this?

**Here is my XAML Code:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xct:Popup xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
           xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
           x:Class="SampleProject.Views.SamplePopup" Size="300, 300">

    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Hello Xamarin.Forms!" />
        <Button Text="Close Popup" Clicked="ClosePopup" />
    </StackLayout>
</xct:Popup>
```

Comment: This is not possible, At best you can convert this into a single .cs with codebehind and move it to a single .cs file

Comment: It cant be achieved. Use instead the builtin popup. eg. await DisplayAlert ("Alert", "You have been alerted", "OK");

Answer (score 0):

Not possible I'm afraid. The XCT popup is it's own distinct element, and due to the fact that XAML pages are just partial classes, there's no way to specify multiple "root" elements.

As a comment above says, you could do it all in a single .CS file.

For your use case, it sounds like the [Syncfusion Popup](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/popup/getting-started) control might be more appropriate, since it can be set to the child of a ContentPage, share a common binding context, etc.